# CarouFredSel Example #61 - Vertical instead of Horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, customization, caroufredsel

I am attempting to modify the example set here:

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/61/

...to display the thumbnails vertically, rather than horizontally.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/7XGtM/)**

I have everything set up and the carousel is working fine, but the hurdle I am going over now is the highlighted thumbnail appears at the TOP rather than the middle (I have the thumbnail count down to 3).

here is the modified version of the Javascript that is running the carousel:

```
$(function() {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel'),
        $pager = $('#pager');

    function getCenterThumb() {
        var $visible = $pager.triggerHandler( 'currentVisible' ),
            center = Math.floor($visible.length / 2);
        return center;
    }

    $carousel.carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 746,
            height: (214/746*100) + '%'
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'scroll',
            onBefore: function( data ) {
                var src = data.items.visible.first().attr( 'src' );
                src = src.split( '/large/' ).join( '/small/' );

                $pager.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]', -getCenterThumb() ] );
                $pager.find( 'img' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
            },
            onAfter: function() {
                $pager.find( 'img' ).eq( getCenterThumb() ).addClass( 'selected' );
            }
        },
        pagination: {
            container: '#nav'
        },
        duration: 10000,
    });

    $pager.carouFredSel({
        width: '252px',
        direction: 'up',
        auto: false,
        items: {
            visible: '1',
            width: 252,
            height: (71/252*100) + '%'
        },
        scroll:{
            items: '3',
        },
        onCreate: function() {
            var center = getCenterThumb();
            $pager.trigger( 'slideTo', [ -center, { duration: 0 } ] );
            $pager.find( 'img' ).eq( center ).addClass( 'selected' );
        }
    });

    $pager.find( 'img' ).click(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr( 'src' );
        src = src.split( '/small/' ).join( '/large/' );
        $carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]' ] );
    });

    $('#nav').hover(function() {
        var current = $('#carousel').triggerHandler( 'currentPosition' );
        thumbs.trigger( 'slideTo', [ current, 0, true, { fx: 'none' } ] );
        $('#thumbs').stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, function() {
        $('#thumbs').stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
    });

    $('#nav a').mouseenter(function() {
        var index = $('#nav a').index( $(this) );

        //  clear the queue
        thumbs.trigger( 'queue', [[]] );

        //  scroll
        thumbs.trigger( 'slideTo', [index, { queue: true }] );
    });
});
```

Anyone have any idea on how to change the SELECTED thumbnail from the FIRST in the stack, to the SECOND and still line up with the main Carousel?

EDIT: I thought I was posting the bounty on another question had about this carousel.  So I'll add the other poont I wish to make.

HOW can I modify the code to allow for the images to be contained in DIVs and still function the way I stated above?  I have toyed with the src variable and trigger call, but haven't had much luck in reaching my goal.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/7XGtM/ This jFiddle solves the VERTICAL scrolling, but I cannot figure out how to wrap the images in DIVs and still get the code to work properly.  The FULL BOUNTY will need to solve that puzzle.

Comment: For more insight on what I'm looking to do, and what the bounty SHOULD HAVE been for (I apologize for setting THIS question as the bounty, it's my first one), PLEASE VIST THIS QUESTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177804/image-billboard-issues

Comment: the JSFiddle, unfortunately, is not working for me.  there are a few console errors

Comment: @Irvin Zhan - The only errors I was getting when I wrote it were broken images.  I modified the linked jFiddle to include the issue that I am currently looking for (getting the rotator to work when wrapping the images in DIVs), but I don't think anyone is paying attention to that portion of the question.

Comment: definitely trying to help, but I cant replicate the behavior until the carousel is working.  I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: thumbs is not defined `

Comment: @Murphy1976 you have thumb and $('#thumbs') in your js but not in your html

Comment: @Irvin Zhan, didn't mean to come across as ungrateful. Didn't think there were any errors other than the broken images.  I have completely removed the THUMBS as they are not needed.

Comment: definitely didnt feel that way at all!  glad you got the issue solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/geqakupe/10/edit

I changed this line: `var src = data.items.visible.first().find('img').attr( 'src' );` in `on before` event and add this css rules:

```
#carousel div{
   position:relative;
}
#carousel {
   width: 800px;
   height: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position:relative;
}
#carousel h1{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:105px;
   font-size:30px;
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: I am currently waiting for the block to be released so I can award you your bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this example will help you:
http://jsbin.com/geqakupe/4/edit

You should set `directon:"up"` and `height:"100%"` options. You also need to change the positioning element `#pager-wrapper` and set different `height` and `width` to it.

Comment: As stated in the appended comments of the question, I have figured that part out, I meant to place the bounty on another question that deals with this same carousel, but I need to wrap the carousel images in DIVs.  I sincerely apologize for the confusion.